# why ng-repeat not working in angular js (using directives)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat with custom directive but i am getting error .can you please tell me how to remove this error

here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/uj8b3hL8T6MjoKSZyjsc?p=preview
custom directive
// Code goes here

```
angular.module('ui.directive',[]).directive('newDir',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            data:'='
        },
        replace:true,
        templateUrl:"pop.html",
        controller:function($scope){
           console.log($scope.data)
        },

        link :function(scope,element,attr){
            element.click(function(){



            })
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error generated is pretty self explanatory:

`Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'newDir' must have exactly one root element. pop.html`

Essentially you need to make sure your template has one root node.  You've appended a `br` tag on the end.

Change:

```
<div><h1>{{str.name}}</h1><p>{{str.category}}</p></div></br>
```

To:

```
<div><h1>{{str.name}}</h1><p>{{str.category}}</p></div>
```

Furthermore,

Your template is referencing `str` however the scope variable is `data`.  Change your template:

```
<div><h1>{{data.name}}</h1><p>{{data.category}}</p></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eUgmU45quL0VoNLY19ek?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/uj8b3hL8T6MjoKSZyjsc?p=preview .still getting undefined not a function

Comment: That's a different issue..  Do you want us to debug your code until it works?

Comment: Ok I will try to resolve if you get any success please post the anser

Comment: Look into jqlite on the angular site.  There is NO `.click` method.  it isn't jquery.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element  You will either need to use `bind` or include jquery.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/uj8b3hL8T6MjoKSZyjsc?p=preview when I remove scope:{
            data:'='
        }, and  data="str" from html it works why

Comment: why the above plunker work when i remove scope and attr from html

Comment: I updated the answer.  You might want to read the angular docs on directives.